# Getting results from select statement in web service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have written a very simple web service that selects the top one result from a table in my SQL DB. I am having a problem calling that class in my web service. I have 3 variables in my class inside my web service. I just want to be able to assign the variables to a set of variables in my project where I am using the web service.

I have another class in my web service where I am inserting into my DB and it is working fine, so I know the web service is working.

This is what i have:

**Web Service**

```
[OperationContract]
void ViewDetails();

[DataContract]
public class ViewDetails
{
    string titleView = string.Empty;
    string descriptionView = string.Empty;
    string authorView = string.Empty;

    [DataMember]
    public string TitleView
    {
        get { return titleView ; }
        set { titleView = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string DescriptionView
    {
        get { return descriptionView ; }
        set { descriptionView = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string AuthorView
    {
        get { return authorView ; }
        set { authorView = value; }
    }
}

public ViewDetails ViewDetails()
    {
        string titleView;
        string descriptionView;
        string authorView;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 [My_Title] AS 'Title', [My_Description] AS 'Description', [My_Author] AS 'Author' FROM [TBL_My_Table]", conn);

        SqlDataReader rdrDetails = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (rdrDetails.HasRows)
        {
            titleView = rdrDetails.GetSqlString(rdrDetails.GetOrdinal("Title")).ToString();
            sescriptionView = rdrDetails.GetSqlString(rdrDetails.GetOrdinal("Description")).ToString();
            authorView = rdrDetails.GetSqlString(rdrDetails.GetOrdinal("Author")).ToString();
        }           
        conn.Close();

        return new ViewDetails
        {
            TitleView = titleView,
            DescriptionView = descriptionView,
            AuthorView = authorView
        };
    }
```

**Where I would like to fill variables with query results**

```
 public Page1()
 {
     this.InitializeComponent();
 }
```

Can anyone help me grab the 3 variables I am filling in the web service and bring them to the above class to display on my screen?

**Example of what I am trying to accomplish**

```
    private void btnView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        string author = string.Empty;

        //this is what I think I should be able to do
        author = client.ViewDetailsAsync.TitleView;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web service isn't actually *returning* anything.  It grabs the data, stores that data in three local variables, then ends.  Never actually using the `ViewDetails` class or providing the caller with those values.

Change your web service method to return a `ViewDetails`:

```
public ViewDetails ViewDetails()
{
    // your code
}
```

Then return an instance of that object from the method:

```
public ViewDetails ViewDetails()
{
    // your code

    return new ViewDetails
    {
        TitleView = titleView,
        DescriptionView = descriptionView,
        AuthorView = authorView
    };
}
```

Then any time something calls your web service method, it will receive the values fetched by that method.

Comment: I have updated my answer with you edit. It is giving me the error "use of unassigned variable titleView". I know what that means, but I am assigning that variable a value.... It is doing it for all 3 variable in the return

Comment: @Code: Good catch.  The code is only assigning to those variables within an `if` block.  If that condition is not met, they're unassigned.  Just initialize them with default values.  Something like: `string titleView = string.Empty;` and so on.

Comment: Perfect, let me give it a try now and see if I can call it in my other project now.. Now the real fun begins! Stand by

Comment: Hmm, ok. So I posted an example above at the bottom of my question. How can I call the 3 return variables from my web service in my other project like above? Can't seem that get that....

Comment: @Code: At that point you're basically asking, "How do I call a WCF service?"  Surely whatever WCF examples/tutorials you're following show that?  MSDN provides a walk-through here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx

Comment: Yes, I have done that. I added what I am doing to my example at the bottom of my question. I think I should be able to do that last line. But "TitleView" is not an option after the "." on "ViewDetailsAsync"....

Comment: @Code: `ViewDetailsAsync` is a method, you need to use parentheses to invoke it: `ViewDetailsAsync()`.  Also, the name implies that it's an asynchronous method, so it's probably going to return a `Task<ViewDetails>` and you'd need to await the result of that task.  That's a whole other topic.  And since you're in the context of an event handler, which *must* return `void`, awaiting asynchronous operations can get tricky.  Your simplest approach would probably be to use the non-async version of the method.

Comment: Yeah... you are right. That's a whole other beast. Thanks alot for all your help. I am going to read into all of your suggestions and go from there!